# My Handpresso got leakage after leave it with some air pressure built in. Could it be worse?

Tags: espresso-machine

Today, I got my Handpresso at work to have some coffee.

When I picked up and pressed valve, I heard air escaping sound. That means there was still some air pressure inside chamber! I used it last Friday, and I forgot to bring it home to clean. So, according to my memory, I've left it almost 2.5 days with air pressure built in chamber.

At first, I was little worried. And when I poured water into reservoir, water is leaking through valve. But strangely, I cannot hear any air leakage from valve or reservoir during brewing process. I've pumped it without water, and still looks like no air leakage from device.

When I reached this point, I'm really worrying that I've broke my Handpresso because of my mistake. Is this situation OK? If not, how can I check and fix water leakage?

Answer (score 1):

Pressure may have built up as a consequence of the residual water and such inside the device and environmental temperature/pressure changes.

It should be okay, and it seems to still be working. Make sure you thoroughly clean it just because you left it for a couple of days. Other than checking for any visible deformities (especially around the silicone sealed areas), if its still working it and tastes fine it likely is not broken.